# How to pass a function containing pymongo db to rq queue (bypassing the inabillity to seralize _thread.lock)?

Tags: python, serialization, redis, pymongo

I have a db and a service that monitors it. I want to enqueue calls regarding said db to an `rq.Queue`:

### callback.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


db_client = MongoClient(username='root', password='pass').db.collection


def do_something(db):
    while not list(db.find({})):
        print('empty db')
    print('found something')
```

however, every try I had doing something like this

```
from redis import Redis; from rq import Queue; from allocator import db_client, do_something
Queue(connection=Redis()).enqueue(do , (db_client, )
```

resulted in

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

How can I bypass this and allow the queued function to interact with the db?

Things I have tried:

1. Using another serializer (dill - `TypeError: cannot pickle 'sqlite3.Connection' object`)
2. Wrapping `do_something` in a class that owns the db - same error